# Can not find module '@angular/core' error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am working on a basic Angular2 sample using NodeJS , and the editor 
i am using is atom.

I have npm installed angular2(2.0.0-beta.17) and typescript

```
npm install angular2
npm install -g typescript
```

In my main.ts am importing

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

For the above line editor is displaying "Can not find module '@angular/core".

What is that I am missing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Package name for angular core is @angular/core.

Read quick [start guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) regarding all the packages needed for angular 2.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 3):

Angular2 no longer uses the package [`angular2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2), but rather a list of different packages under the tag [`@angular`](https://www.npmjs.com/~angular). This list includes, but is not limited to:

- `@angular/common`
- `@angular/core`
- `@angular/compiler`
- `@angular/forms`
- `@angular/platform-browser`
- `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`

Please refer to the [5 Min Quickstart Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) for further details.

> Angular2 used the [`angular2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2) package up until the [release candidate](https://github.com/angular/angular/releases/tag/2.0.0-rc.0), when it introduced a [breaking change](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02) by moving the different modules to their own packages, and all of these under the new [`@angular`](https://www.npmjs.com/~angular) tag.